# Detecção de mudanças do Angular não está funcionando para componente de notificação

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, front-end, visual-studio-code

Olá.

Estava implementando um componente de notificação para apresentar, em uma tela, mensagens de sucesso ou erro para as operações do usuário.

Ele se baseia em um `Subject` em um `Service` compartilhado, onde alimenta uma lista em um HTML que fica como filho do componente de cabeçalho. O problema é que quando publico um novo alerta, nesse Subject, a tela não atualiza, pois a mudança no atributo não está sendo detectada, já tentei abordagens com o uso de `NgZone` e `ChangeDetectorRef`, mas nenhuma delas surtiu resultado.

Poderiam me auxiliar?

Todo o código está neste [repositório](https://github.com/RenanFR/opinionatedWeb/blob/master/src/app/shared/notification.component.ts).

Comment: Fica difícil entender os dislikes na pergunta, está categorizado corretamente e pesquisei exaustivamente antes de publicar só que casos semelhantes ao meu geralmente apontam solução com esse ChangeDetectorRef o que não funcionou no meu caso, além disso o código para consulta e reprodução está todo no repositório anexado, se não tem a resposta simplesmente ignore a pergunta ou aponte o erro e peça o detalhamento, não desclassifique gratuitamente pois isso diminui a visibilidade da mesma, complicado lidar com a má vontade de alguns

Comment: Não entendi muito bem a sua pergunta, mas você quer utilizar o mesmo `Component` de mensagem em outros Componentes? Se for isso, acho que esse vídeo pode te ajuda (ou a sequencia deles, até o 90) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5c7qo26j728&list=PLGxZ4Rq3BOBoSRcKWEdQACbUCNWLczg2G&index=82&t=0s

Comment: Por favor poste o codigo referente a pergunta inves de links externos

Comment: Certo @EduardoVargas, vou me atentar a isso, mas imagino que no caso de vários arquivos relacionados fica mais simples e menos verbosa a questão só relacionando o repositório mas vou seguir sua orientação

Comment: @EdwardRamos é só mais um componente de layout como o de cabeçalho ou rodapé mas com o propósito de exibir alertas emitidos por certas ações no sistema, o problema é que mudanças em atributos vinculados a esse componente não são refletidas em tela pois a detecção não está notificando o template, mas vou olhar a série de vídeos sim para ver se há alguma outra abordagem, obrigado

Comment: O ideal é que todo o código necessário para reproduzir o problema esteja na própria pergunta, e links sejam apenas complementos - por favor [**leia o FAQ**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5489/112052), que explica melhor todos os motivos. Se o código original é muito grande, tente reduzi-lo para um [mcve].